# Sample Java code to connect to AWS S3 using VPC endpoint

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am new to AWS, and was looking for a java sample for connecting to AWS s3 using vpc endpoint. I tried below snippet from my local machine, but it is not working. if i use same creds and login using SFTP client(WinSCP), i am able to login.
I want to use S3 to stream files from it, so that i can do file processing faster in my code. Also this code won't be running in EC2 instance.

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("*****", "*******");
    ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration().withRequestTimeout(50000);
    clientConfig.setUseTcpKeepAlive(true);
    AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("vpce-************-*******.server.transfer.us-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com", Regions.US_WEST_2.toString()))
            .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
            .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig)
            .build();
```

People in my team are just replacing legacy sftp connection details, with new S3 VPC endpoint, and using legacy code to upload files. But I don't think we are fully utilizing s3 features by doing that. 
Expert help would be appreciated here.

Comment: Sorry, but are you asking for advice on how to best replace SFTP, or are you having a particular problem with the code? Is this code running on an Amazon EC2 instance in the same subnet as the VPC Endpoint? Feel free to edit your question to add more details, including what problems you are facing.

Comment: edited my question

Comment: Your actual business requirements are still unclear. What are you actually wanting to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with the information presented in your question.

`vpce-************-*******.server.transfer.us-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com` is **not** an Amazon S3 VPC endpoint.  It's a VPC endpoint for a service called [AWS Transer for SFTP](https://aws.amazon.com/sftp/) which provides a managed SFTP gateway that connects to an Amazon S3 bucket.

An [S3 VPC Endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/) is different, requires no client configuration, and has no special endpoint hostname -- these are transparent and used automatically when created and correctly configured inside a VPC.  And they provide a REST interface, not SFTP.

In both cases, VPC endpoints can only be used from inside a VPC, so you wouldn't be able to access an AWS Transer for SFTP endpoint from outside of EC2 in any event.

But that's not, strictly speaking, why it isn't working.  The code you have would also not work inside a VPC, and the root of the problem is that `AmazonS3 s3client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder` builds an S3 **REST** client, not an **SFTP** client.  This client can't be used with an AWS Transfer for SFTP endpoint, either Internet-facing or inside a VPC, since such an endpoint is not what `AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration()` is designed to be used with.  The endpoints for use with the SDK are [found here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html). For us-west-2, the endpoint for ipv4 connectivity is `https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com` and for ipv4/ipv6 is `https://s3.dualstack.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on the S3 VPC endpoint vs VPC endpoint for AWS transfer for SFTP..